# Mathematical Canon

Tags: reference-request

Sometime ago I resolved to read through a prodigious book collection known as the [The Great Books of the Western World](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Books_of_the_Western_World)--a rather lovely collection which I would encourage anyone to read through, if they have not already read these books. In this collection are various literary, philosophical, and even mathematical and scientific works, such as Newton's Principia and Euclid's Elements

The most lovely feature of this collection is the historical ordering of these books, which gives one an perspective of how people have lighted upon ideas which we, sometimes, take for granted. This is something I am very interested, how one comes upon ideas and the reasoning that leads to these ideas or conclusions, as it tends to make the concept more comprehensible and reasonable.

My question for today is, does anyone know of a mathematical canon, or has anyone contrived of their own mathematical canon? After having scoured the internet for such a canon, I have not found very much. I ask, because I would like to experience mathematics from a historical perspective, to go through the deductions of history that lead to mathematics as it is today, which, I think, will furnish me with a grander appreciation and understanding of mathematics.

In short, what are important mathematical works, present and past (but more so from the past), and in what order ought they be read? The same request would apply to a "physics canon," if anyone knows of such a thing.

EDIT: If no mathematical canon can be found, I propose that the eminent users of math stackexchange create one!

Comment: You might be interested in reading [The Calculus Gallery: Masterpieces from Newton to Lebesgue](http://www.amazon.com/The-Calculus-Gallery-Masterpieces-Lebesgue/dp/0691136262) by Dunham, and also [Journey Through Genius](http://www.amazon.com/Journey-through-Genius-Theorems-Mathematics/dp/014014739X/ref=pd_sim_b_1?ie=UTF8&refRID=13DK1NRA6W06F133XSWK) by the same author.

Comment: Also, Stephan Hawking prepared *On the Shoulders of Giants*, which is a massive book of collected works of some of the greatest mathematicians - Euclid, Archimedes, Newton, Laplace, Galois, and the list goes on. It is not an easy read, due to the outdated language and sophisticated material.

Comment: If you don't mind stopping 60 years ago, James R. Newman published in 1956 a wonderful four-volume set called [The World of Mathematics](http://www.amazon.com/The-World-Mathematics-4-volumes/dp/B001KI9LJC/). You can get a Dover paperback edition for less than US$50, but I highly recommend the original hardback version. It's over 2500 pages and takes you from ancient Egypt through Einstein.

Comment: @shoover I believe the mathematics library at my school is in the possession of this collection! I should have a look at it.

Comment: @Mack: Check out the Chicago Undergraduate Mathematics Bibliography: https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~abhishek/chicmath.htm

Comment: 'Princeton Companion to Mathematics' which was published in 2008 by Timothy Gowers, June Barrow-Green, and Imre Leader. Terry Tao wrote parts of it, and a blog post about it here - https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/09/29/princeton-companion-to-mathematics/

Comment: Over time, every major publication house tries to put together such canons, so several such canons exist. I would look at curated math bookshelves in Goodreads. Also, the BBC documentary on the story of math is great! It is impossible to have a complete canon because even as late at 1980s we find new tombs with ancient mathematical works!  Control+F "1983" in this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nine_Chapters_on_the_Mathematical_Art 
I'm curating these for my personal study. If you bump into any canon of canons, please do comment back here! :)